Numba throws `type error` for my gradient descent
I am trying to build my MNIST Classifier from scratch in Numba, but it throws the error of type error for np.dot(), however, when I run these functions without NUMBA Jit, I find out all the types are of float32 and run without error, I cannot understand whats wrong here.
The code is :
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

# Load the dataset
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Flatten images
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1).astype(np.float32)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], -1).astype(np.float32)

# Normalize data
X_train /= 255.0
X_test /= 255.0

# Convert labels to integers
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int8)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int8)

# Logistic regression model parameters
num_features = X_train.shape[1]
num_classes = 10
learning_rate = 0.1
num_iterations = 1000

# Numba-optimized logistic regression functions
@njit
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z))

@njit
def compute_cost(X, y, theta):
    m = X.shape[0]
    h = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
    cost = -(1.0 / m) * np.sum(y * np.log(h) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h))
    return cost

@njit
def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    m = X.shape[0]
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        h = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
        gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / m
        theta -= learning_rate * gradient
        if i % 100 == 0:
            cost = compute_cost(X, y, theta)
            print(f'Iteration {i}, Cost: {cost}')
    return theta

@njit
def predict(X, theta):
    h = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
    return np.argmax(h, axis=1)

# Add bias term to X_train and X_test
X_train_bias = np.hstack([np.ones((X_train.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.float32), X_train])
X_test_bias = np.hstack([np.ones((X_test.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.float32), X_test])

# Convert y_train to one-hot encoding
y_train_one_hot = np.zeros((y_train.size, num_classes), dtype=np.float32)
y_train_one_hot[np.arange(y_train.size), y_train] = 1.0

# Initialize theta (weights)
theta = np.zeros((num_features + 1, num_classes), dtype=np.float32)

print(type(X_train_bias[0][0]), type(y_train_one_hot[0][0]), type(theta[0][0]), type(learning_rate), type(num_iterations))
print((X_train_bias[0][0]), (y_train_one_hot[0][0]), (theta[0][0]), (learning_rate), (num_iterations))



# # Train the model
theta = gradient_descent(X_train_bias, y_train_one_hot, theta, learning_rate, num_iterations)

# # Predictions on test set
y_pred = predict(X_test_bias, theta)

# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = np.mean(y_pred == y_test) * 100
print(f'Accuracy on test set: {accuracy:.2f}%')

And this is what my error looks like
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0a5c11357e7d> in <cell line: 74>()
     72 
     73 # # Train the model
---> 74 theta = gradient_descent(X_train_bias, y_train_one_hot, theta, learning_rate, num_iterations)
     75 
     76 # # Predictions on test set

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    466                 e.patch_message(msg)
    467 
--> 468             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407                 raise e
    408             else:
--> 409                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
    410 
    411         argtypes = []

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function dot>) found for signature:
 
 >>> dot(array(float32, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C))
 
There are 4 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'dot_2': File: numba/np/linalg.py: Line 525.
        With argument(s): '(array(float32, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
       No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic _impl>) found for signature:
        
        >>> _impl(array(float32, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C))
        
       There are 2 candidate implementations:
         - Of which 2 did not match due to:
         Intrinsic in function 'dot_2_impl.<locals>._impl': File: numba/np/linalg.py: Line 543.
           With argument(s): '(array(float32, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C))':
          Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
            TypingError: np.dot() arguments must all have the same dtype
         raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/np/linalg.py:563
       
       During: resolving callee type: Function(<intrinsic _impl>)
       During: typing of call at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/np/linalg.py (582)
       
       
       File "../usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/np/linalg.py", line 582:
                   def _dot2_codegen(context, builder, sig, args):
                       <source elided>
       
               return lambda left, right: _impl(left, right)
               ^

  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1086
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'dot_3': File: numba/np/linalg.py: Line 784.
        With argument(s): '(array(float32, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: missing a required argument: 'out'
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numba/core/typing/templates.py:784

During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function dot>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-16-0a5c11357e7d> (43)


File "<ipython-input-16-0a5c11357e7d>", line 43:
def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    <source elided>
        h = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
        gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / m
        ^

Note: I am running this on google colab

It seems you mix 32-bit float with 64-bit one. Is this intended? If yes, you can convert the 32-bit array to a 64-bit one (safe) or the 64-bit to a 32-bit one (fast). I guess Numpy does this conversion implicitly (the safe one: 32-bit to 64-bit). Alternatively, it can be because sigmoid returns a 64-bit array in Numba. I think you should explicitly convert constants to 32-bit ones if you want 32-bit values everywhere (1.0 is a float64 constant). You can also add signature for types to be guaranteed.

Oh and you tagged the question CUDA but there is no CUDA here. Numba's njit does not run the code on GPU but the CPU (sequentially by default). For more information about this, please read the Numba's documentation.
